# Changing layout via zooming

Tags: css, zooming

My goal is to change my layout when zooming, in much the same way that I change my layout with a window resize Event.

After a lot of searching, I have concluded that you cannot detect a zoom Event in every Browser. Therefore, I have concluded that I should use @media queries for zooming just as I do for window resizing.

Having said that, here is what my @media queries looks like:

```
/* LARGE window */
@media (min-width: 601px) {
    .mainContent {
        font-size: 125%;
    }

    .infoHeaderTextStyle {
        font-size: 160%;
    }
}

/* SMALL window */
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .mainContent {
        font-size: 100%;                                             
    }

    .infoHeaderTextStyle {
        font-size: 100%;
    }
}
```

Works great for window resizing.

So, for zooming, what rule follows `@media` ??

Is it?

```
@media (font-size > 20px) {
   /* ZOOMED IN */
}

@media (font-size <= 20px) {
   /* ZOOMED OUT */
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure there is a surefire way. You can work with the [`resolution` media feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40media/resolution) - see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/oor82gf2/), but it always behaves as if zoomed in on high-resolution devices such as phones and Retina screens. And it isn't implemented in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

While zooming a screen of width for eg.,1000px to 200% the browser assumes it as a width of 500px and apply the styles in @media (max-width: 500px){}.

Hope you understand this.
If you want to write css for zooming you have to code media queries for smaller devices and try experimenting.

Comment: You can see at https://angular.io/ if you zoom it on desktop then you will see mobile version

Comment: Yes, but as I wrote in my comment to the question, then Retina screens will behave as if they're always zoomed in.

Comment: My suggestion while you adjust font-size in css, make use of "rem". Sorry if this doesn't work I never used a retina screen :)

Please let me know if it works.